Recover corrupted qcow image
I have a VM running on qemu on ARM from a qcow2 image, unfortunately my image was damaged and now doesn't boot.
Using qemu-img check returns over 7 000 errors (so much that the logfile is too big for pastebin...), mostly unaligned clusters, L2 entries corrupted.
Mounting with guestfs fails, though I am able to attach the image using qemu-nbd but cannot mount the partition afterwards. fsck on the nbd states that the superblock is unreadable, and none of the backups seem to work.
I don't really need to repair the image itself, but it would be nice to recover the data, is there any chance I'm getting anything off of it ?
Nothing on it is critical so I don't have backups, but recovering the data would save a lot of time.
